# How do I test an endpoint using Jasmine/Karma?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method in one of my components that hits an endpoint like this...

```
private async getRolesAsync(): Promise<void> {
    const roles = await this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').toPromise();
    this.data = roles;
  }
```

Notice I have a fake endpoint in there, but what I'd like to know is how do I test that in a unit test? I want a unit test that tests to see if the endpoint works, i.e, it returns a 200 success.

I'm using Angular 13 as my application framework and Jasmine/Karma as my unit testing framework.

Comment: You need to use `HttpClientTestingModule` to test http calls. In a unit test you shouldn't be sending http calls but you should be mocking their responses and you can assert their request body, method, etc. Check this article out on how to do it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-testing-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Please use this end-to-end running code for the resolution of all your issues. [image: Coverage Logs]

**spec.ts file -**

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

describe("AppComponent", () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController)
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('#getRolesAsync should return expected data', async (done) => {
    const expectedData = {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: "delectus aut autem",
      completed: false
    };
    (await component.getData()).subscribe(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
      done();
    });
    const testRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    testRequest.flush(expectedData);
  });
});
```

**component.ts file -**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   async getData(): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const roles = await this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    return this.data = roles;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here are the errors I get when I put that code in...

Cannot find name 'mockRequestResp'. 
Cannot find name 'ResponseModelFromGETReq'. 
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'.
Cannot find name 'mockRequestResp'.
Variable 'result' is used before being assigned.
Cannot find name 'mockRequestResp'.

Comment: Please try again now, I have updated the code.

Comment: Now, I get the following errors...

(TS) Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'.

(TS) Object is possibly 'undefined'.

Comment: You can convert Promise to Observable to overcome this error.

Comment: I tried "converting" it to an Observable by writing this code...

public async getRolesAsync(): Promise<Observable<void>> {

But that didn't work. I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Please refer to the updated code with attached Karma Logs.

Comment: Does the code resolved your concern

Comment: No, the issue still persists.